# Comparing table attributes in ArcGIS 10(ArcInfo)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, attribute-table

I'd like to compare attributes of two point layers . the layers have some similar records and i try to find these . ArcGIS 10.1 has a tool to comparing attributes but i could'nt find any similar tools in ArcGIS 10 . How can i compare two attribute and find similar records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**
I use this when I have already done a join of my data.
Selecting other fields that are similar (or not).
(Sorry  I was out of office and assumed as I use it a key field between the two tables)

In the select by attribute tool.
(Found under the selection pull down)
Type.
Mytable1.feild1 = mytable2.field2
**Another method (alternative to Aaron's [which his will work great for you])

Is to do a join on the fields that have the same values and select the "Keep only matching records" option.**
[image: Select]

Comment: Neson I could'nt use this syntax . could you please describe more detaile? . when i use this syntax, ArcGIS select all of Mytable1.field1 .

Comment: Thanks All. @Brad said i can use join. it helps me alot .I use Join and relate and solve the problem .

Answer (score 9):

Try using [Feature Compare (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000004000000):

> Compares two feature classes or layers and returns the comparison
>   results. Feature Compare can report differences with geometry, tabular
>   values, spatial reference, and field definitions.

Alternatively, use [Table Compare (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000007000000):

> Compares two tables or table views and returns the comparison results.
>   This tool can report differences and similarities with tabular values
>   and field definitions.

Comment: based on @Areon table compare is great for me and i use it for another problem .

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple GP tools available in ArcGIS 10, such as '[Find Identical](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000054000000)' and '[Delete Identical](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Delete_Identical/001700000053000000/)'. Please refer to these Esri KB articles to find out more:

- [HowTo:  Identify duplicate field values](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38700)
- [HowTo:  Find duplicate or coincident features](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/39236)
- [FAQ:  Does ArcGIS provide a way to identify or remove features with duplicate geometries?](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/36031)

Just in case you want to get access to more advanced tools on GIS data management within your business workflows regarding to finding similar features both geometry and attribute wise, consider taking a look at the [ArcGIS Data Reviewer 10](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//010200000022000000) (the link on managing duplicate geometries).

Comment: I have two layers ( layer A and layer B) and i want to compare records of a field in layer A to layer B. the location of points not same. i don't have any duplicate data .